# How to ignore a @SQLDelete annotation in certain cases

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, sql-delete, soft-delete

I want to implement soft deletion, but still be able to delete permanently. Is there any way to ignore a declared @SQLDelete() annotation, or maybe say:

```
@SQLDelete("IF expression THEN UPDATE statement ELSE delete statement")
```

EDIT:

This is the entity in question.

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@FilterDefs({
    @FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "tenantId", type = "string")}),
    @FilterDef(name = "deleteFilter")
})
@Filters({
    @Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantId"),
    @Filter(name = "deleteFilter", condition = "deleted = false")
})
@SQLDelete(sql ="UPDATE Antwort SET deleted = true, date_modified = NOW() WHERE ID = ?; DELETE FROM Antwort WHERE deleted = true AND kundenentwurf_id IS NOT NULL", check = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)
public class Antwort implements TenantSupport, ISoftDeleteModel{

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String tenantId;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean deleted;
private Date dateModified;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Organisation organisation;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Projekt projekt;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Kundenentwurf kundenentwurf;

private Integer nummer;
private String frage;
private String antwort;


//getters, setters and contructors...

}
```

Comment: my idea is write procedure on data base site, which will invoke logic operation, because this query is native and it is fine solution

Comment: @PiotrRogowski hmmm.. i would rather not write anything in the database directly, because when deploying, that would be another step i would need to think about. Can it be done through pure hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

I explained this in more details in one of my [Hibernate Tips](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/permanently-remove-when-using-soft-delete/). Here is the short version of it:

When you call the remove method on your `EntityManager`, Hibernate will execute the SQL statement defined in the `@SQLDelete` operation.

You can’t deactivate the `@SQLDelete` annotation. So, if you want to remove the record from the database permanently, you can’t use the remove method of your `EntityManager`. You need to execute a SQL DELETE statement using a JPQL, [Criteria](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/) or [native](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/use-native-queries-perform-bulk-updates/) query.

Here is an example of a JPQL DELETE statement:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

// do something ...

// add this if you fetched the Book entity in this session
em.flush();
em.clear();

Query query = em.createQuery("DELETE Book b WHERE id = :id");
query.setParameter("id", 1L);
query.executeUpdate();

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

In case you fetched the `Book` entity you want to remove within your current Hibernate Session, you need to call the `flush` and `clear` methods on your `EntityManager` before you execute the DELETE statement. This ensures that all pending changes are written to the database before you remove the record.

Comment: Thx, i will probably end up doing it this way, but is it possible to execute 2 statements in the @SQLDelete() annotation. I got a entity "Book" that i want to soft delete, except if the foreign "author_id" is set, then i want to hard delete. I though its possible to say `@SQLDelete(sql ="UPDATE Book SET deleted = true WHERE ID = ?; DELETE FROM Book WHERE deleted = true AND author_id IS NOT NULL")`. But this dosnt seem to work. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That should be possible. Do you get any error message?

I tried this mapping and it works:

`@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE book SET status = 'DELETED' WHERE id = ? AND version = ?; DELETE FROM book WHERE status = 'DELETED' AND title IS NULL", check = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)`

Comment: I get: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000.  But if i execute the SQL via MySQL workbench then it works without any problems

Comment: my actual code is `@SQLDelete(sql ="UPDATE Antwort SET deleted = true, date_modified = NOW() WHERE ID = ?; DELETE FROM Antwort WHERE deleted = true AND kundenentwurf_id IS NOT NULL", check = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)`

Comment: Please post your Antwort entity

Comment: I just posted it